# Google map marker showinfowWindow customize Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

In my app, I have to show the information about the marker at position.
This is my work code.

```
mPerth = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(PERTH)
        .title("Perth")
        .snippet("Population: Perth")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));
mPerth.showInfoWindow();
```

This looks like this image:
[image]

I want looks like this iamge:
[image]
If you have any method, please vote me.

Comment: I want to move the infoWindow to right of the marker. I didn't find that solution till yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
marker.setInfoWindowAnchor(1f,1f)
```

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker#public-void-setinfowindowanchor-float-anchoru,-float-anchorv

Edit:

For a custom infoWindow you have to make a concrete implementation of **GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter** and inflate your *custom_info_window_layout.xml* file in the getInfoWindow(Marker marker) method.

```
public class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

Activity context;
CustomInfoWindow(Activity  context){
    this.context =context;
}

@Override
public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
    View view = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window_layout, null);

    TextView title =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
    TextView snippet =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_snippet);

    title.setText(marker.getTitle());
    snippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

    return view;
}

@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
    return null;
}
```

}

And finally set this **CustomInfoWindowAdapter** on the map.

```
map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(MainActivity.this))
```

Comment: Thank, It works for me. I needed to the customize the InfoWindow. If you know this, please add comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
static final LatLng PERTH = new LatLng(-31.90, 115.86);
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(PERTH)
                    .anchor(0.5,0.5)
                    .rotation(90.0)
                    .infoWindowAnchor(0.5,0)); // add this line
```

[image]

**Specifies the point in the marker image at which to anchor the info window when it is displayed. The default is the top middle of the image.**